# Cannot create new wchar_t *

Tags: c++, new-operator, operator-keyword, wchar-t

I have this operator overloader.
My program crashes at the creation of the new `wchar_t` array.

```
myObject &operator += (const myObject &s) {
    wchar_t *cat = wcscat(data, s.data);
    int len = wcslen(cat);
    wchar_t *test = new wchar_t[len + 1]; //this is killing!
    wcscpy(test, cat);

    delete data;
    data = test;

    return *this;
}
```

Does anybody know what's happening?

EDIT complete class definition

```
class myObject
{
    private:
        wchar_t *data;
    public:
        myObject() { data = 0; }
        ~myObject() { delete data; }

        myObject &operator += (const myObject &s) {
            wchar_t *cat = wcscat(data, s.data);
            int len = wcslen(cat);
            wchar_t *test = new wchar_t[len + 1];
            wcscpy(test, cat);

            delete data;
            data = test;

            return *this;
        }
};
```

Comment: What does "this is killing" mean?

Comment: Couldn't you save yourself a lot of trouble by having the class hold an `std::wstring`?

Comment: Is `data` big enough to hold `s.data` on the end? You're also invoking UB by using the wrong `delete`.

Comment: That line is causing the program to crash.

Comment: @chris my program hasn't been able to get past the creation of that new array. So it hasn't have anything to do with the object right?

Comment: Can you post your whole class definition and test code?

Comment: How are you calling the operator? If you say `x +=x;` then the call to `wscat` will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @HansElsen, Undefined behaviour can do what it wants, including crashing somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code contains, at least, two rather obvious problems:

1. You allocate data apparently using `new wchar_t[n]` but you release it using `delete p` rather than using `delete[] p`.
2. The likely cause of your problem is that you concatenate two strings into the memory of one string and *then* allocate enough memory to copy the data over.

You probably want something more along the lines of this:

```
myObject &operator += (const myObject &s) {
    size_t len = wcslen(this->data) + wcslen(s.data);
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> tmp(new wchar_t[len + 1]);
    wcscpy(tmp.get(), this->data);
    wcscat(tmp.get(), s.data);
    delete[] this->data;
    this->data = tmp.release();
    return *this;
}
```

Actually, I think you want to use `std::wstring`: this class already provides the logic, probably in a more efficient form anyway.

Comment: "probably in a more efficient form" - for one thing, it won't have to measure the lengths of the strings with `wcslen`, or skip over the destination string like `wcscat` does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it.
My reason for not using the wstring is that I'm trying to learn to work with these arrays so I know whats happening

Comment: @HansElsen It's a good idea to learn what goes on behind the scenes. Once you've learned that don't forget to go back to doing things the easy way.

Comment: Thanks all, this solution worked. I also made a more basic solution with 2 for-loops to fill the new array. But the problem is clear now. From now on I can use wstrings haha.

Comment: You shouldn't use any `for`-loops for things like this, though! Ideally, you strings now how many characters they have and expose iterators (possibly to `wchar_t const`) to their elements. Filling the new array would then look something like this: `std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::copy(this->begin(), this.end(), tmp.get()));`

Answer (score 2):

As Dietmar says (but with a bit more detail what *probably* happened behind the scenes):

1) The call `wcscat(data, s.data)` has overrun the end of the buffer pointed to by `data`. If it didn't overrun, then you wouldn't need to allocate a new buffer, since the existing one would be big enough. I expect it *isn't* big enough.

2) As a consequence of overrunning the buffer, data structures used by the memory allocator are trashed. This causes a crash when you try to allocate memory. It could just as easily cause a crash when you free memory, or never crash at all.